# How to alter column type of a primary key and connected foreign keys?

Tags: mysql

I have a primary key named item_id. This column is connected as a foreign key in other tables.

If I try to change the column type one by one I have this: #1025 - Error on rename...

How do I change the column type for all columns?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to:

1. lock both tables with LOCK TABLES
2. drop the foreign key
3. change the PK type
4. re-create the foreign key (with the correct type)
5. UNLOCK TABLES